# Matching column values in sequence sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, rank

I have a table A

```
col1 col2
1    81,123
2    90,99,100
3    4
```

And table 2

```
col1  col2
1     23
1     123
2     90
3     4
```

I want to join both the tables on first matching sequence

for example :

for col1 value =1 : 23 does not match neither with 81 or 123 so it would move to next i.e 123. 123 matches so it is the answer

---

### the final output

```
col1   col2
1      123
2      90
3      4
```

my query is :

```
 select * from
(
select t1.col1,t2.col2,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.col1 order by t1.col1) as dupRow 
from @table1 t1 inner join @table2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.col1
)a 
where a.duprow =1
```

Comment: What have you tried and how is the behavior different from what you expect? Show us your code.

Comment: @LewsTherin : updated

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, give this a try:

```
;with cteA as 
(
    select a.col1, split.a.value('.', 'varchar(100)') as string  
    from  (select col1, cast ('<m>' + replace(col2, ',', '</m><m>') + '</m>' as xml) as string from  a) as a cross apply string.nodes ('/m') as split(a)
) 
select a.col1, a.string as col2
from cteA a join b as b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.string = b.col2
```

Not sure if it will work in all cases, needs some testing.
Here you can find a [demo](http://rextester.com/QLJO99535) of this code.

> EDIT:

This will give you always only one match, the first one (randomly), per each `col1`:

```
;with cteA as 
(
    select a.col1, split.a.value('.', 'varchar(100)') as string  
    from  (select col1, cast ('<m>' + replace(col2, ',', '</m><m>') + '</m>' as xml) as string from  a) as a cross apply string.nodes ('/m') as split(a)
) 
select col1, col2
from
(
    select a.col1, a.string as col2, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.col1 order by a.col1) as nr
    from cteA a join b as b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.string = b.col2
) t 
where nr = 1
```

I wrote another piece of code [here](http://rextester.com/GCTQ54607) as a demo.
The first code I wrote would give you multiple rows if the join condition is met twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM
(SELECT B.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by B.COL1 order by B.COL1) AS DUPROW
FROM TABLEA A INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.COL1 = B.COL1
AND B.COL2 IN (SELECT * FROM SPLIT(A.COL2))
) R
WHERE DUPROW = 1

    --funtion to split comma seperated varchar to table
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] ( @strString varchar(4000))
    RETURNS  @Result TABLE(Value BIGINT)
    AS
    BEGIN

          DECLARE @x XML 
          SELECT @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(@strString,',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)     
    INSERT INTO @Result            
    SELECT t.value('.', 'int') AS inVal
    FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)
        RETURN
    END
```